# Play video in a webview

Tags: android, html, video, webview

My application get a list of articles from a json file.
Every article has an attribute content. This attribute content will contain html code that o will display in my webveiw.

All is working good (text, images, style ...), except videos. I am always getting error webview file is inaccessible.

There is an example of content i have:

```
    <p>Text text Text textText text</p>\n
<p><iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/73297417\" width=\"300\" height=\"164\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```

The error i get here: The web page adress file://player.vimeo.com/video/73297417 is temporary inacessible. I know that my web view is doing something wrong.
I implemented this html code in my wordpress site and video worked fine. Why this is not working on android.

Same problem for Youtube

[image]

Comment: Looks like the issue is in the URL, it does get resolved to file://, which would be a file on the local filesystem. Maybe try to remove the leading "//" from the URL, or more likely use a leading "https://" instead and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @bgse, your URL is off. file:// calls files on the local filesystem. You need to be using http:// or https:// for calling content over the web. Try something like this:

```
src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/73297417\"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the embed code.

> String preHtml = "\n\n\n\n\n";
>                                     String postHtml = "\n\n";
>                                     String str1 = preHtml + vdeoPath + postHtml;
>                                     mWebView.loadData(str1, "text/html",
>                                             "utf-8");